# Is there a faster way to search for a particular text in a VB solution?

Tags: vb.net

I need to scan all files on our solution (aspx, js, ascx, etc)
Our solution contains 22 projects all in all.

What I need to accomplish is to search for all files which contains
"img=" in its content (not filename containinf "img")

I don't want to do this manually of course (opening and checking files one by one)...Can anyone share any ideas on how I can do this faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use Agent Ransack which is free:

http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home

Alternatively, you can do it from within Visual Studio by doing Ctrl+Shift+F and selecting 'Look In' = 'Entire Solution'

Comment: I vote for ctrl shift f.  I use it routinely on a solution with ~50 projects without problem.

Answer (score 0):

TextSeek is another solution for your problem. And you can use Ctrl+Arrow key to browse all hit results across files.

https://www.textseek.net/